# Best way to resolve BeanConflict in spring

Tags: spring, rest

I have a central library, which contains model package

```
central-lib.jar
     -->central.com.dbservice
               --StudentDBImpl.java
     -->central.com.model
               -- 
               --
```

I also have project specific common-jar

```
my-project-common-lib
     -->project.com.model
               --  
               --
     -->project.com.dbservice
               --StudentDBImpl.java
```

DemoSpringProject includes both jar central-lib.jar and my-project-common-lib

```
DemoSpringProject 
          -- build.gradle
                -- dependencies {

                  -->central-lib.jar {
                      ?? how to exclude "central.com.dbservice" package ??
                  }

                  -->my-project-common-lib

                }
```

When I start the server I get BeanConflictException...

Here I want to exclude the package (central.com.dbservice)  from central-lib.jar..

**How can I exclude that..???**

Comment: This shouldn't be an issue based on what you're describing. The Java classes belong to different packages, so they're treated as unique beans. What's the actual stack trace? And are you using correct package names?

Comment: Even I thought that... The packages are different.. so there won't be any conflict issue... But it was throwing an exception of bean conflict.